# How to pass carat character "^" as a parameter in XSLT

Tags: xslt, unexpected-token

How to pass carat character "^" as a parameter in XSLT

Below line tries to call a template but I'll get an error which is "unexpected token '^' in the expression"

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="sg[@ty='TST']/fs/f[@ix='5']/vl"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="^"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This is some part of my data and I need to split it
TEST12^Dr K Test^^^^^^^LAB^^^^DN^GOS&TFHS Hospital

My template is:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenizeString">
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <!--  body of template -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the following line of code

```
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="^"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'^'"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'&#94;'"/>
```